# Is there a limit to the number of games I can have going?

Tags: draw-something

I thought I read some where the limit is 4 games in draw-something, but I am now on my 5th one.. I am simply wondering if there is a limit to the number of games I can have going at any given time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can have up to 20 games with random people.

There doesn't appear to be a limit for games with Facebook friends, though.